# create table name from other table value

Tags: mysql

i am doing a simple shopping cart for my assignment. currently i am doing the planning for relational databases. here are the part of the requirements:

1. multiple seller with multiple products
2. multiple customer
3. cust can add many items in a cart
4. a cart (having many items) is saved after a transaction so cust can view them in transaction history
5. so the cart has cart_id tied to cust_id
6. if there are 10 transaction, 10 carts will be saved
7. each cart has many items.

this is the flow (my attempt) -

a cart with cart_id=10001 is create when cust=11 adds 1st item
lets say cust added 5 items in cart
transaction completed. 2 things happen:

1. cart_id is saved to master_cart table with cust_id
2. (on my part) a table is created with the name 10001 having prod_id and quantity

my prob is about the list how do i create a table having the name of the cart_id? also, is this the right way?

this is my draft for db.

[image]

is this the right way or how do i create table with the name based on other table row values?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to create a new table for each new cart. What happens if you have 1000 carts??? And if you have 100000 carts???

Comment: @nacho i thought it is better that way, rather than having a table that holds super long list of items history of all cust. that'll be very long and might affect response time. by segregating into its own tables is in a way it is 'filtered' from thousands of other customers. hope that make sense

Comment: I am sorry but it doesn' t make sense

Answer (score 0):

You should not create a table for each cart. Dynamic information should be in table contents, not names.

You should have a single `cart_items` table with `cart_id` as a column.

```
CREATE TABLE cart_items (
    cart_id INT,
    prod_id INT,
    quantity INT,
    UNIQUE KEY (cart_id, prod_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (cart_id) REFERENCES cart (cart_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (prod_id) REFERENCES product (prod_id)
);
```

Comment: something like this?

cart_items
____________  
cart_id prod_id quantity
10001 86            3
10001 64            5
10001 3            6
10001 5467    8
10001 456           8.9
10002 456             3 
10002 664       5
10002 457            6
10002 85            8
10002 98          8.9

Comment: There's no formatting in comments, so that's unreadable. But I think it's right.

Comment: I'm not sure how you can have fractional quantities.

Comment: sorry for the formatting issue... glad u able to read it. but my concern is, if there are 100 cust, having 100 carts in history with 100 items, wouldnt that make the cart_items table hold very large rows? wouldnt that impact performance? my thinking was by having its own table it is somewhat 'filtered' from other customers so query from a cust is light weight..

no worries on the fractional quantity, just an illustration. :)

Comment: Don't worry about it, this is exactly what databases are optimized for. Millions of rows is normal in database tables.

Comment: Thank you good sir! appreciate the fast response and good explanation!